# Adding textfields in the page on button click event

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have total six textfields on page. by default it will show only two textfields.It also has one button "add text" . When I click on button it will add one textfield at a time . So, How  can I implement the functionality in extjs.

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.require('*');
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var i = 0;

    Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        renderTo: document.body,
        text: 'Add',
        handler: function(){
            ++i;
            form.add({
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Field ' + i
            });
        }
    })

    var form = new Ext.form.Panel({
        bodyPadding: 5,
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 300,
        items: []
    });

});
```